# Copying one input field to a group of other input fields in jQuery

Tags: jquery, input

Hi I have the following code (I've removed some of the bloat, but everything needed is here.

```
<div class="item">
<div class="img_url"><input type="text" value="/siteimg/Designs/special-request.jpg" id="DT_Image_1" name="DT_Image_1" /></div>
<div id="copy_to_all_1"><a href="#">Copy to all</a></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div class="img_url"><input type="text" value="" id="DT_Image_2" name="DT_Image_2" /></div>
<div id="copy_to_all_2"><a href="#">Copy to all</a></div>
</div>

<div class="item">
<div class="img_url"><input type="text" value="" id="DT_Image_3" name="DT_Image_3" /></div>
<div id="copy_to_all_3"><a href="#">Copy to all</a></div>
</div>
```

These div's are loaded dynamically, so there could be a lot more in there. I need a way of finding the current ID and then copying it into all of the other input ID's listed.

So in this case if I clicked the link "Copy to all" on the first item, the other input fields would be populated with "/siteimg/Designs/special-request.jpg"

I need abit of jQuery magic to get this ready to go.

Comment: So you want us to write this for you? Did you try anything to make it work?

Comment: Yeah, apologies I did paste my code in but the browser crashed. Before I could paste, the person below already posted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[id^="copy_to_all"] a').live('click', function(){
        $('.img_url input').val($(this).closest('div.item').find('.img_url input').val())
    });
});
```

P.S.: Your markup sucks. Should be this:

```
<div class="item">
    <input class="img_url" type="text" value="/siteimg/Designs/special-request.jpg" id="DT_Image_1" name="DT_Image_1" />
    <a class="copy_to_all" href="#">Copy to all</a>
</div>
```

And the corresponding function from above:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.copy_to_all').live('click', function(){
        $('.img_url').val($(this).prev('.img_url').val())
    });
});
```

---

*Edit: Saw the*

> *the divs are loaded dynamically*

*part of the question, changed `click()` to `live()` just to be safe.*

---

*Edit 2:* Bonus working fiddles [with original](http://jsfiddle.net/9DggD/) and [with decent markup.](http://jsfiddle.net/9DggD/1/)

Comment: Yeah, to be honest the coding is much worse than I've even pasted it haha, it's surrounded in lots of tables. I just cut it down to try and get the point across. I was just missing the .closest function :(

Comment: Well, the only thing I can suggest to you is that you take care of your markup first and foremost.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This:
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').live('click', function() {
            parentDivTagId = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
            index = parentDivTagId.substring(12, (parentDivTagId.length));
            copyString = $('#DT_Image_' + index).val();
            $('input:text').val(copyString);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="img_url">
            <input type="text" value="/siteimg/Designs/special-request.jpg"
                id="DT_Image_1" name="DT_Image_1" />
        </div>
        <div id="copy_to_all_1">
            <a href="#">Copy to all</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="img_url">
            <input type="text" value="" id="DT_Image_2" name="DT_Image_2" />
        </div>
        <div id="copy_to_all_2">
            <a href="#">Copy to all</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="img_url">
            <input type="text" value="" id="DT_Image_3" name="DT_Image_3" />
        </div>
        <div id="copy_to_all_3">
            <a href="#">Copy to all</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```